# How can I query MongoDB in a blocking way ? (not sure if this is the right way though)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Let me introduce my problem : I'm currently developing a web app using Node.js, Express and MongoDB (mongoose driver), and I would like, when the user requests `/save`, to generate an unique ID (made of random letters and digits) in order to redirect the request to `/save/id`.

Therefore I want my `/save` route to query MongoDB for a list of existing IDs, and generate a random ID which is not present in the list.

Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: You shouldn't do this. You should just use MongoDB's built-in ObjectId when creating a new document. The unique id should not be exposed to the user in the URL.

Comment: MongoDB already does this. The _id field automatically creates a random id, which in normal use-cases will always be unique.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/ Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Oops, I was not precise enough. Actually I do want a to use custom ID (let's call it a key) in addition to the default MongoDB's _id, and I do want that key to be exposed in the URL, as this will be the only way to access a document :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both the terms and their relation to each other are a bit unclear her. We first have to see a more precise definition of what the `_id` field and its default field type of `ObjectId` are.

#### The `_id` field

For each document, there has to be a mandatory, unique `_id`. The only constraint of that field is that its values have to be unique. In case this field is not explicitly contained in the incoming data, MongoDB will create one with an ObjectId. However, the `_id` can hold any value, even subdocuments, as long as it is unique. The following is a perfectly valid documents and might even make sense in some use cases:

```
{
  _id: {
    name: "Roger",
    surname: "Rabbit"
  }
}
```

To enforce uniqueness, a [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) is created over `_id`.

#### ObjectId

`ObjectId` is the default field type of `_id`. It is an alphanumerical, truncated representation of some values, namely

- seconds since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)
- machine identifier, which itself is constructed from various values, iirc (though I can not remember how)
- the ID of the process generating the ObjectId
- a counter whith random initialisation

#### The answer to your question

Contrary to what has been told many times and here again, there is absolutely now drawback in using a custom value for the `_id` field instead of the default ObjectId. Quite the contrary: If you have a field which is (semantically) unique and you query by it, that is an awesome candidate, since most likely you will need an index on this, anyway. Let's take some easy example: the social security number (SSN) in an insurance company application. Compare the next two documents:

```
{
  _id: <SomeObjectId>,
  SSN: 12345678,
  name: {
    first: "Roger",
    last: "Rabbit"
  }
}
```

In order to query for the values you need, you need at least 3 indices here: The default on on `_id`, a unique one on SSN and a multikey one on `name`. For any given query, only one index can be used. This might become a problem in aggregations (which the math guys in your insurance will do *a lot*). Additionally you have the pretty useless ObjectId as additional data, which can become costly if you have several million datasets.

Now compare to this document:

```
{
  _id: {
    SSN: 12345678,
    firstname: "Roger",
    lastname: "Rabbit"
  }
}
```

First of all: we hold the same information without useless data and we have only a single index, which can easily translate to Gigabytes of free RAM. Second of all, we added some implicit semantics, because the uniqueness of an entry is enforced over SSN and the complete name, which might become handy if a name is changed due to a marriage. Wether or not this makes sense is a design decision. I decided to use the full name as part of the `_id` mainly for the sake of this example.

So it is perfectly valid to create an `_id` yourself as long as you ensure it is unique. And here is the problem. Creating something unique isn't that easy. For the above example, it might be a hash of `_id`'s values (never use clear text SSNs!). This could be done like this (kudos to @maerics):

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
shasum.update("Roger");
shasum.update("Rabbit");
shasum.update("12345678");
console.log(shasum.digest('hex'));
// Something like "0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33"
```

You could either add this hash to the `_id` field , though it might make sense to have a separate field, increasing our index count to two.
*Please note that this hashing procedure is only necessary if you would otherwise disclose sensitive data in the URLs!*

However, just using ObjectId for the `_id` because it is a convenient way to create a unique value is lazy system design. As shown, smart system design may save you Gigabytes in RAM, which easily translates into multiple servers for large databases.